# Unix socket connection to MySql with Java to avoid JDBC's TCP/IP overhead?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, unix-socket

Is it possible to make a Unix socket connection to MySql with Java to avoid JDBC's TCP/IP overhead?

Does anyone know a library (or a few libraries, perhaps) that makes this possible?

Comment: You might want to port MySQL C API http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c.html to Java using Swig http://www.swig.org/. If you have the time and if it's all worth it :)

Comment: I think what the original poster wanted was a MySQL JDBC connector that could use the local unix socket instead of TCP. As others pointed out, the standard JDBC connector does lots of clever stuff and unless you have confirmed that the network connection is a bottleneck you're risking premature optimization. I don't see a standard way to use sockets in the MySQL JDBC connector to do this.

Comment: I'm thinking you're taking the same approach as I have, if you don't want the mysql server exposed to the web... use iptables and such to block the port, but local apps can still access under the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Also the mySQL JDBC driver has been polished over a long period and has several optimization tweaks , like caching of metadata. I would be surprised that the JDBC developers would have left a lot of TCP/IP overhead in the driver.

Going over JNI to the C based implementation would probably cost more in jumping to native code than can be gained from reduced TCP/IP overhead.

If you really want to cut out the TCP/IP overhead you might consider using an embedded database like sqlite, derby or hypersonic.

Comment: `I would be surprised that the JDBC developers would have left a lot of TCP/IP overhead in the driver.` How should I understand this? How JDBC developers have influence on TCP/IP?

Comment: I mean that the developers of the mySQL JDBC driver would have tuned the networking code to avoid unnecessary overhead while using TCP. When you connect to a port on the same machine, then the kernel skips a lot of the overhead associated with TCP/IP. On the other hand it still is TCP/IP over a loopback network and the data has to go through the network layers. The JDBC developers of course cannot influence TCP/IP outside what's provided by the Java API. I would be surprised if this theorethical overhead would have a significant impact though, especially with a database behind it.

Answer (score 1):

JDBC is only an interface specification. It does not add any TCP/IP overhead. If there is overhead it is caused by the JDBC driver. There are also JDBC drivers for in memory or file databases and don't use TCP/IP at all.

The MYSQL JDBC driver is a JDBC Type 4 driver. That means it does not use any native code to access the database. If Java has no method to access unix sockets, the driver can not use them either.[<sup>[1]</sup>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j.html)

If you really want to use a unix socket maybe it is possible to use MySQL's ODBC driver which seems to supports unix sockets and then use a JDBC-ODBC bridge to access it from Java.

Answer (score 0):

You could always take the C library and wrap it yourself. I think it supports UNIX sockets.

Can I ask how you've determined the TCP/IP overhead to be an issue? How did you narrow the problem (that I assume you're having) down to that?

Is the problem just the connection overhead as opposed to the packet overhead? If establishing connections is taking too long a connection pooling library (such as the one in Apache commons) would handle that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use junixsocket, https://github.com/kohlschutter/junixsocket

It's a JNI-powered library that provides access to AF_UNIX sockets using the standard Java Socket API, and also comes with a MySQL connection factory.