# How to connect to database in java without jdbc and other frameworks?

Tags: java, jdbc

Is there any other way to connect to the database other than making a jdbc connection or using frameworks which internally use jdbc.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: why not JDBC connection? what's your difficulty behind ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397016/java-jdbc-alternatives

Comment: It depends on the database. Most DB servers typically communicate directly via sockets

Comment: You could (theoretically...) create a JNI binding for your database's native C/C++ API (e.g. OCI in case of Oracle RDBMS)

Comment: All of the JDBC alternatives in the link above are built on JDBC, so you're still using it.

Comment: One reason why you may want to, and why I came here:  Because you are access user data that is stored in their database, and you don't know what DBMS they have.  You don't want to include several DBMS in your application if you don't have to.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, it's possible.  But not likely.

You'd have to understand the protocol that the database vendor expected completely.

You'd have to write your own client to converse with the vendor's listener on the server side.

It can be done, but I doubt that you or I would be up to it.

The big question is: why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JDBC ODBC Bridge ... not recommended though..

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Connection conn = getConnection();
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    // st.executeUpdate("drop table survey;");
    st.executeUpdate("create table survey (id int,name varchar(30));");
    st.executeUpdate("insert into survey (id,name ) values (1,'nameValue')");

    st = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM survey");

    ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();

    int numberOfColumns = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
    System.out.println("resultSet MetaData column Count=" + numberOfColumns);

    st.close();
    conn.close();
  }

  private static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
    String url = "jdbc:odbc:northwind";
    String username = "";
    String password = "";
    Class.forName(driver);
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not available in 64 bit JVMs.  And this is still JDBC.

Comment: but we are not using any third party drivers......

Comment: Yes you are, you just don't know it.  You're using the bridge driver that Oracle/Sun wrote.  They're a third party.  And it's still JDBC.  See the first four letters in the driver and connection URL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771594/unix-socket-connection-to-mysql-with-java-to-avoid-jdbcs-tcp-ip-overhead

Comment: Right, but that's not what your code says.  And they are agreeing with my recommendation: write your own client from scratch, understanding the protocol completely.  You're making my point.

Comment: then you know the answer... why would someone like to do that anyway... do you really need any such thing?

Comment: yes indeed i did make ur point. i just pasted the right answer ... so, one needs reinvent the wheel rather then use it if this question is ever to be answered.

Comment: Four and a half years later and you're coming back with this comment?